# How to select attribute specific values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, select

I have table like

[image]

I need to select if **R_no values is more than two same values** and in ANGLE select **first three numbers common and more than three attributes is same**

[image]

Finally I want to select like blue highlighted attributes.

Comment: To select multiple instances of R_no: summary statistics with a summary field of FID/OBJECTID case field of R_no to create a table with counts, optionally use table select where count_FID > 1 to create a new table with just R_no values that have a count of more than 1 instance then join by attributes R_no to R_no in the summary table extract and then finally select where count_FID > 1, right click on the layer and choose create layer from selected features and then remove the join on the selection layer - this will leave you with a layer where all the rows have a instance of R_no more than 1.

Comment: thanks sir, but it is to lengthy. And what about Angle select starting three letters same attributes if more than three values.

Comment: Again, you can use the same technique to select from the selected layer but this could be simplified with python and dictionaries using a search cursor then iterating the first dictionary by key to select the matching R_no, ANGLE and DIST; the two-from-three duplication match can be evaluated and selection added to an existing selection (starting from no selection) of a layer. This is fairly advanced python, do you have reasonable python ability?

Comment: i don't have knowledge about python so could u please give VB Script querry for above.

Comment: I don't know VB Script, VB.net with ArcObjects I do know but that's far too much to write for a single question. Use Model Builder if you want this to be repeatable and save into a toolbox.

Comment: #Hornbydd help me sir

Comment: The three selected rows does not have the same angle, what do you mean? You want to select the first Three values for each R_no Group if group size is >2? Why do you talk about the angle field

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear. If you want to select first three rows if number of features in each R_no group is larger than two, code below should work. Execute in python window with the table/feature class added to the map. Im using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to Group.

```py
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict

layer = 'somelayeraddedtoArcMap' #Change
group_field = 'R_no' #Change

oid_field = arcpy.Describe(layer).OIDFieldName
d = defaultdict(list)

#Group oids together by Group_field
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,[group_field, oid_field]) as cursor:
    for group, oids in cursor:
        d[group].append(oids)

oids_to_select = []
for group, oids in d.iteritems(): #d.items() in python3/ArcGIS Pro
    if len(oids)>2: #if more than 2 in group
        oids_to_select.extend(oids[:3]) #:3 add first Three oids to list

sql = "{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(layer, oid_field), tuple(oids_to_select))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=layer, 
                                       where_clause=sql)
```